# Animating Button alpha to 0 and the 1 after a delay does not work

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and ran into an issue when trying to fade a button out and then back in. In my app i'm using

```
 myButton.animate().alpha(0f).duration(200)
```

to fade a button and after some other interaction with ui elements i'm doing

```
 myButton.animate().alpha(1f).duration(200)
```

and this works fine. What i want to do now is fade the button out and then back in almost immediately so i tried:

```
 myButton.animate().alpha(0f).duration(200)
 myButton.animate().alpha(1f).duration(200).startDelay(300)
```

Unfortunately this two line do not seem to do anything. The button does not change alpa at all and stays visible throughout. Can anyone please explain what's happening? Does it have something to do with animations being transient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use withEndAction instead of just listing the commands one after another.

```
myButton.animate().setDuration(200).alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myButton.animate().setDuration(200).alpha(1f).start();
            }
        }).start();
```